# iPad: QuartzCore: multiple shapes

Tags: xcode, ipad, quartz-2d

I'm new to quartzCore and i'm not getting used to it so easily.
I want to draw some basic shapes in a view and rotate/magnify each one of them independently.

Can you give me some directions or ideas on how to do that ?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Actual Quartz operations aren't guaranteed to be very speedy — if you want a bunch of separate shapes which rotate/scale separately then you're better off putting each in a separate view and performing the rotation and scaling by adjusting the transform property. The compositor in iOS works by caching the image of all views and adjustments to the transform simply adjust how the cached image is drawn to the screen. Hence pixellation would be an issue if you zoomed in too far, but even without going into the mechanisms such as CATiledLayer for providing different levels of detail asynchronously and on demand (as in Safari, where zooming in shows the pixellated version of the view and then transitions to a full resolution one as soon as it is ready), you could just size the views at their maximum size initially and then scale them down.

Without knowing exactly your level of expertise, you'll want to declare one or more custom UIView subclasses that can draw one of your shapes. You'll then want to implement your own [-drawRect:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/drawRect%3a) with the CoreGraphics calls within it.

The transform property on a UIView takes a CGAffineTransform and can be animated in the CoreAnimation sense.

If one of your custom UIViews were simply to draw a diagonal line from the top left of the view to the bottom right (a useless thing to do, probably, but for the purposes of example), you might have:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    // we're relative to the inside of the view, so...
    CGPoint points[2]; 
    points[0] = CGPointMake(0, 0); 
    points[1] = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);

    CGContextSetGrayStrokeColor(context, 0.6, 0.6);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextStrokeLineSegments(context, points, 2);

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Then you could do, for example:

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);
```